how to specify include directory in R install.packages(url, destfile, method)
I have managed to install ggplot2 in R with the command
install.packages("https://cloud.r-project.org/src/contrib/ggplot2_3.5.1.tar.gz", repos = NULL, type = "source")

This required installing dependencies isoband, rlang, scales and vctrs, all installed with the command similar to the above.
Now I need to install sf. sf has units as a dependency. Apparently I have to specify where the include and lib directories of uudunits2 are.
Below is part of the configure output, from where the error starts
....
checking for XML_ParserCreate in -lexpat... no
checking for udunits2.h... no
checking for udunits2/udunits2.h... no
checking for ut_read_xml in -ludunits2... no
configure: error: in `/tmp/Rtmp56px4o/R.INSTALLb9ef233f9f71/units':
configure: error: 
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
  Configuration failed because libudunits2.so was not found. Try installing:
    * deb:  (Debian, Ubuntu, ...)
    * rpm: udunits2-devel (Fedora, EPEL, ...)
    * brew: udunits (OSX)
  If udunits2 is already installed in a non-standard location, use:
    --configure-args='--with-udunits2-lib=/usr/local/lib'
  if the library was not found, and/or:
    --configure-args='--with-udunits2-include=/usr/include/udunits2'
  if the header was not found, replacing paths with appropriate values.
  You can alternatively set UDUNITS2_INCLUDE and UDUNITS2_LIBS manually.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

When I quit R and run
sudo apt install libudunits2-dev

I get that
libudunits2-dev is already the newest version (2.2.28-3).

"Locate udunits2" gives
/usr/include/udunits2.h 

and several libraries in
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu (i.e. libudunits2.a,libudunits2.so, libudunits2.so.0, libudunits2.so.0.1.0)

How do I specify the include and lib directories for the units package to install within R?
Help will be appreciated."

My apologies for all who may be spending their effort looking at my problem. I managed to install udunits2 within R. So I think units will also install eventually.
